# Adjust accessibility of derived methods when changed on parent

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I decided to change access modifier of a method which is overridden in multiple classes. So now I need to adjust accessibility modifier in all of them.

I assumed that is so common operation that Visual Studio (2019) should be able to do it automatically for me, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Did I miss something or "manually" is the only way to go?

Comment: you could do a simple find and replace...

Comment: @jeroenh In fact, in my case it would do the trick, but it is not general solution. You can imagine overloaded methods with parameters renamed in derived classes. In such case there is no way to at once update the specific method in all classes using find and replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not available out of the box.

Find and replace could mostly work:

```
Find in project/solution: public override void MyMethod(
Replace with: 'protected override void MyMethod('
```

[Roslynator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=josefpihrt.Roslynator2019) is a free/open source Visual Studio extension that has a large amount of extra refactorings, a.o. [change accessibility](https://github.com/JosefPihrt/Roslynator/blob/master/docs/refactorings/RR0186.md).

For example, this changes this:

```
class Base
{
    protected virtual void Method() { }
}
class Derived : Base
{
    protected override void Method() { }
}
```

to this:

```
class Base
{
    public virtual void Method() { }
}
class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Method() { }
}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks. It seems just strange to me it is not included in "Change Signature" - you can reorder or remove parameters in all derived methods at once, but you cannot change accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

You could click on the `x references` tag above the class name to get a list of derived classes:

[image]

Comment: I do have list of them because they cause compilation error. I just would like to avoid editing then one by one.